# "is 'desired behaviour' possible?" Questions

Tags: discussion

I recently encountered

> [image: this question]

which essentially boils down to:

1. OP wants behaviour X
2. OP provides example code Y to illustrate X
3. Question: Can X be achieved? if so:
4. Question: How?

I was cautious when approaching this for a two reasons:

- It seemed like a "Give me the codez" question
- A brief scan of example Y made me think "why wouldn't that work?"

So I opened up my IDE, copied in the code (also provided data consistent with the OPs request, an array containing 3 arrays). Lo' and behold, it works without any modifications or debugging.

What should I do with this? As you can see I posted a comment, asking the OP if they'd tried their own code, should I do anything else or wait for a reply?

Comment: [Why is "Is it possible to:" a poorly worded question?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7274/31260)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The original question has been deleted by the OP. Based on your description, I think the comment you left was good, and it would be appropriate to flag for close as Off-topic -> cannot be reproduced.